# Outlook shows wrong user name

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Here's the background:
A company has a CAO user, that gets taken over by a new CAO. Basically - a name on the account was changed in AD, while the login "CAO" and the email addy "cao@..." remained the same.
Old CAO's name was Theresa, the current guy is called Brian.
Software: Exchange 2010, Outlook 2010, Win7pro, standard settings for everything.

Everything works great except for two very annoying things in outlook 2010:

1. In sent items, the name above a shown sent email is Theresa and not Brian (see screenshot)
2. When printing email from outlook, the name in bold letters above the printout is also Theresa's.

[image: screenshot - outlook 2010]

When I hover above "Theresa" in the outlook sent items view, the info box shown is actually saying "Brian".

So far I have done the following:

- Checked through OWA - no issue there
- Rebuilt a new offline address book and made it default
- recreated the outlook profile
- wiped the entire local user profile and rebuilt that from scratch

The fact that OWA doesn't have this problem, tells me it's got to be a local or offline issue, but I have rebuilt the local profile with only the data outlook can possibly get from exchange, no local PSTs, and while it showed up properly for a few minutes at first, we've got Theresa back in out face shortly after.

Please help :)

Comment: What does microsoft have to say?

Comment: I have never found their techsupport to be anywhere near good

Comment: nowhere near good?

Comment: Does the mailbox have a Me/Self contact saved with the name Theresa?  If not, Outlook 2010 caches a lot more stuff in the actual mailbox.  I say save what you need in a PST and recreate the mailbox in Exchange from scratch.

Comment: 1. Nobody knows what a CAO user is, at least I don't. Only use acronyms if you're sure that everyone knows what they are. 2. This is why it never pays to rename a user account instead of creating a new user account.

Comment: @mdpc nowhere near.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Where can I check for a Me/Self? I didn't know such a thing existed. As for recreating from scratch, that might be the next step if I don't find out where the old name is coming from.

Comment: @joeqwerty 1. just "CAO", as in a C-level exec, who is represented by his position, and not the current name that exec goes by. High turnover in the higher echelons of power :) 2. I know, and I wouldn't do that myself, keeping users to their names instead, with additional SMTP addresses whenever required, but I'm dealing with very strong minded people here who "have been doing it this way since foreva, eh!"

Comment: Gotcha. What does CAO stand for?

Comment: @joeqwerty chief administrative officer (or was that accounting?)

Comment: i guess this could sort the issues:
http://outlookproblemshelp.com/outlook-problems-and-support/outlook-problems-like-incorrect-info-in-the-from-field/